# AngularJS UI: how to apply my css class to overwrite the original css class of ui grid

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

As the title says, for example, I want to create a CSS class named `myViewport` to overwrite `ui-grid-viewport` (`ui-grid`).

Comment: Go for it then? Any questions?

Comment: I want to discard the horizontal scroll

Comment: Have a google for css specificity, it will tell you all you need to know

Comment: @Pete thank you, this maybe helpful, I need it, and I want to know if I can define a name for my ui-grid and apply the css with id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should have been discussed several times here. You can disable the horizontal bar with enableHorizontalScrollbar option. I don't think you would require css to achieve this unless you are trying out something different.

```
$scope.grid = {
enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0
};
```

It can take any one of the following values:

```
0 = disable;
1 = enable;
2 = enable when needed;
```

And note that you would need to pass the uiGridConstants to your controller.

You shall also check this github repository for more info.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid

Comment: It doesn't work for my case, In the chrome, there is an element.style{ overflow: scroll } which effects always, even if i have added $scope.grid in my controller.js

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution it's CSS element>element Selector, I add an id to parent element for example:

```
<div id=""test>
    <div>
        <div class="ui-grid-viewport(object)">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in the style.css
the name of class should be div#test >div> .ui-grid-viewport{}
this is a solution not simple, because I should find the position of ui-grid-viewport.